# Unexplained syntax error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#ifndef _CXS_H
#define _CXS_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE
#include "mex.h"
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
#ifndef NCOMPLEX
#include <complex>
typedef std::complex<double> cs_complex_t ;
#endif
extern "C" {
#else
#ifndef NCOMPLEX
#include <complex.h>
#define cs_complex_t double _Complex
#endif
#endif

#define CS_VER 2                    /* CXSparse Version */
#define CS_SUBVER 3
#define CS_SUBSUB 0
#define CS_DATE "Jun 1, 2012"       /* CXSparse release date */
#define CS_COPYRIGHT "Copyright (c) Timothy A. Davis, 2006-2012"
#define CXSPARSE

#include "SuiteSparse_config.h"
#define cs_long_t       SuiteSparse_long
#define cs_long_t_id    SuiteSparse_long_id
#define cs_long_t_max   SuiteSparse_long_max

         ........................

typedef struct cs_ci_sparse  /* matrix in compressed-column or triplet form */
{
    int nzmax ;     /* maximum number of entries */
    int m ;         /* number of rows */
    int n ;         /* number of columns */
    int *p ;        /* column pointers (size n+1) or col indices (size nzmax) */
    int *i ;        /* row indices, size nzmax */
    cs_complex_t *x ;    /* numerical values, size nzmax */
    int nz ;        /* # of entries in triplet matrix, -1 for compressed-col */
} cs_ci ;

   ....................
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I am getting a compilation error:

```
Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

for the line:

```
cs_complex_t *x ;    /* numerical values, size nzmax */
```

Due to the size of the file some irrelevant parts are missing. Is there something that could explain this error given this code segment? This project is a simulator like Spice.

Comment: Reduce that code before posting here.

Comment: Is `NCOMPLEX` defined?

Comment: You have `*x` in the code, but just `x` in the error message. Did you copy the error message correctly?

Comment: @KeithThompson That was markdown eating the *

Answer (score 3):

The code you've posted will lead to exactly this error if the macro `NCOMPLEX` is defined. Both definitions of `cs_complex_t` are enclosed in `#ifndef NCOMPLEX`. So if the macro `NCOMPLEX` *is* defined, `cs_complex_t` will *not* be defined and will thus be an unresolvable identifier when the compiler encounters it in the definition of `cs_ci_sparse`.

I'd say that's a logical bug in the file. If the definition of `cs_complex_t` depends on the absence of `NCOMPLEX`, all uses of `cs_complex_t` should depend on it too.